# Unable to install SmartGWT 4.1p and 5.0p into maven repository

Tags: maven, smartgwt

Since 4.1 version of SmartGWT it is requiered to use isc-maven-plugin

I'm trying to install SmartGWT LGPL 4.1p or 5.0p on my local repository

```
mvn com.isomorphic:isc-maven-plugin:1.1.1:install -Dproduct=SMARTGWT -Dlicense=LGPL -DbuildNumber=5.0p
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
[WARNING] No server configured with id 'smartclient-developer'.  Will be unable to     authenticate.
[WARNING] No downloads found at 'www.smartclient.com/builds/SmartGWT/5.0p/LGPL    /2014-12-01/'.  Response from server:

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 - Error report</title>
  <style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-    color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-fami
ly:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3     {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif
;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-    family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-
color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-    color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,
sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name     {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--
></style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1>
  <hr size="1" noshade="noshade" />
  <p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
  <p><b>message</b> <u></u></p>
  <p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p>
  <hr size="1" noshade="noshade" />
  <h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.41</h3>
 </body>
```

Comment: May I draw your attention to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831911/trying-to-use-smartgwt-but-getting-errors-cannot-read-property-setautodraw-o) here? I can't get SmartGWT to work for me. :/

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
mvn com.isomorphic:isc-maven-plugin:1.1.1:install -Dproduct=SMARTGWT -Dlicense=LGPL -DbuildNumber=5.0p -DbuildDate=2014-11-30
```

Comment: How do we find the latest build if there is a new build affer 2014-11-30? Do we have to run this new step every time there is a new build?   I myself just want the latest stable development version that's all.    And now that we have this, what is the exact dependency that we need in the pom.xml file now?

Comment: For now you can go to http://www.smartclient.com/builds/SmartGWT/5.0p/LGPL and get latest buildDate from there. I got information from Isomorphic some time ago that they are planning to fix this by taking latest buildDate by default if user will not specify this parameter.