# Trying to use SmartGWT but getting errors: "Cannot read property 'setAutoDraw' of undefined"

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to introduce SmartGWT to my existing GWT application.

What I did so far was placing

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
```

into my `client.gwt.xml` and `module.gwt.xml` files. If I run the application, the compilation appears to work. I am not getting any errors from the code server - just a few warnings about deprecated classes but nothing else.

However, if I just import a SmartGWT button like this:

```
public LandingPageViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper = Util.placeHistoryMapper;

    final LoginPlace loginPlace = new LoginPlace();
    this.aLogin.setHref("#" + historyMapper.getToken(loginPlace));

    // This is "com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Button"
    Button btn = new Button();
}
```

My application breaks and I am getting

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : `Cannot read property 'setAutoDraw' of undefined`

I am quite sure that I'm missing something but the question is what. I am using the latest SmartGWT version `v5.0-p20160115`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.lgpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>5.0-p20160115</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Required by Smart GWT -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.isomorphic</groupId>
    <artifactId>isc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

after installing SmartGWT

```
mvn com.isomorphic:isc-maven-plugin:install -Dproduct=SMARTGWT -Dlicense=LGPL -DbuildNumber=5.0p
```

besides the latest GWT version `v2.8.0-beta1`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/32687-newbee-helloworld-howto-question

Comment: Please check if sc folder with smart client code is included in the war file and if you can see this code in browser developer tools.